# bash chained logical operator execution order, lazy evaluation

Tags: bash

I don't get this:

script: `WORKDIR/sh/script.sh`

```
[ -e filename ]          \
&& echo filename         \
|| [ -e ../filename ]    \
&& echo ../filename      \
|| { echo 'ERROR: failed to find "filename"' 1>&2 ; exit -1; }
```

output:

```
$ cd WORKDIR/sh
$ ./script.sh
../filename

$ cd WORKDIR
$ sh/script.sh
filename
../filename      # <---- WHY????
```

My thoughts:

## 1

```
[ -e filename ]          \ -> false
&&                         -> skip this, it is already false
   echo filename         \ -> don't even try
|| [ -e ../filename ]    \ -> true
&& echo ../filename      \ -> true
||                         -> already true, skip the rest
   { echo 'ERROR: failed to find "filename"' 1>&2 ; exit -1; }
```

## 2

```
[ -e filename ]          \ -> true
&& echo filename         \ -> true
||                         -> already true, skip the rest
   [ -e ../filename ]    \
&& echo ../filename      \
|| { echo 'ERROR: failed to find "filename"' 1>&2 ; exit -1; }
```

version:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: This is exactly why you should never chain these operators.

Comment: This is mainly because the status used by && and || **changes** from command to command. It is controlled both by the `[` command **and** the `echo` command. bash will not "skip the rest".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`&&` and `||` have equal precedence, so:

When a command passes, it will look for the next `&&` and execute it, even if it is not the directly adjacent operator.  You should **never** use more than one of these operators in a single command list.  If more than one is needed you use an if/then construct.

```
$ true && true || echo yes && echo no
no
```

This is very much different than:

```
if true; then 
  true 
else 
  echo yes && echo no
fi
```

---

```
$ if true; then true; else echo yes && echo no; fi
$
```

Or:

```
$ true && false || echo yes && echo no
yes
no
$ if true; then false; else echo yes && echo no; fi
$
```

---

I would write your construct as:

```
if [ -e filename ]; then
    echo filename
elif [ -e ../filename ]; then
    echo ../filename
else
    echo 'ERROR: failed to find "filename"' >&2
    exit -1
fi
```

Comment: Or, more confusingly, `true && false || echo yes && echo no`! (Which illustrates your main point.)

Comment: I like to explain this with this example: `A && B || C` then `C` executes if `A` ***or*** `B` fails.

Comment: Right. I think it’s more correct to say that each command is run if the commands run previously satisfy the condition expressed by the operator immediately preceding it; see for example `true && false || echo yes && false && echo no`. It’s not true that all `&&` expressions are run if the first succeeds.

Comment: "&& and || have equal precedence" this was it! I assumed && is higher than ||.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are hoping that bash does this:

```
(A && B) || (C && D) || E
```

but it actually does this

```
(A && B || C) && D || E
```

Where D executes if *either* B or C succeeds.

Add more grouping:

```bsh
[ -e filename ] && echo filename || {
    [ -e ../filename ] && echo ../filename || { 
        echo 'ERROR: failed to find "filename"' 1>&2 
        exit -1
    }
}
```

or

```bsh
{ [ -e filename ]    && echo filename   ; } || 
{ [ -e ../filename ] && echo ../filename; } || 
{ echo 'ERROR: failed to find "filename"' 1>&2 ;  exit -1; }
```

or use the very clear and readable `if-elif-else` style demonstrated by @Jesse_b.

---

Step-by-step, this is happening:

1. filename is in current directory:

   ```
   [ -e filename ]    \   # test succeeds, status is now 0
   &&                     # status is zero, will execute this branch
   echo filename      \   # echo succeeds, status is now 0
   ||                     # status is zero, do not execute
   [ -e ../filename ] \   # not executed
   &&                     # status is zero, will execute this branch
   echo ../filename   \   # echo succeeds, status is now 0
   ||                     # status is zero, do not execute
   { echo; exit; }        # not executed
   ```
2. filename is in parent directory:

   ```
   [ -e filename ]    \   # test fails, status is now 1
   &&                     # status is non-zero, do not execute this branch
   echo filename      \   # not executed
   ||                     # status is non-zero, will execute this branch
   [ -e ../filename ] \   # test succeeds, status is now 0
   &&                     # status is zero, will execute this branch
   echo ../filename   \   # echo succeeds, status is now 0
   ||                     # status is zero, do not execute
   { echo; exit; }        # not executed
   ```

Comment: I think it's more like `((( A && B ) || C ) && D ) || E`, but it's the same thing, just more parentheses.